# how to control a DC supply's voltage using a micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, power, mosfet

Im trying to complete a home project and I have run into a problem.  I want to control the output of two 18650s to a simple resistor circuit.  I want the output to change based on the changing resistor value that is being read.  I think the best way involves a micro controller and possible  Mosfet. The ohms meter doesnt sound hard due to a simple voltage divider. However controlling power does.  Im using a Cerebot Mx7 and C if this helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the power supply supplying? If it's just resistors (you are heating things?) then PWM might suffice.

Comment: Two 18650s possible a Dc plug and yes I am heating a resistor.  I want to be able to control voltage based on the resistors current ohm reading as its heated.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the equivalent of an adjustable power regulator. There are multiple ways of doing this though:

#### 1. Using a switch-mode buck converter topology

This is the simplest to implement with a microcontroller as long as your microcontroller have both ADC input and PWM output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbWIdu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Power MOSFET M2, D1, and L1 makes the buck converter. Signal MOSFET M1 is used as a level shifter and gate driver. Resistive divider R2 and R3 allows your MCU to sample the output voltage and control the PWM signal as required.

#### 2. Use a linear regulator topology

I would not recommend using this topology as it requires more complicated control, more chips and have worse efficiency than the switch-mode supply above.

You need to have an DAC to generate the target voltage and use op-amp and emitter follower to amplify the DAC output.

Comment: So if I wanted to read the resistance with said micro controller while its powered, would that be possible? Or would i need a separate component to plug in?

Comment: @Jla2804 Are you designing an ohmmeter?